# "Not so much + something as + something"

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

From https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-so-much-sth-as-sth

> I don't feel **angry** so much as sad. (1)

Question 1: Alluding to the sentence above and given that the structure of the afore mententioned phrase is "not so much" followed by "something", is the following correct:

> I don't feel so much **angry** as sad. (2)

Edit:

Question 2: Referring to @chasly - supports Monica's answer, it seems that they differ by word order. Is one order preferred over the other?

Comment: Yes, *[not] **so much** [as]* in such contexts can come *before* the "diminished" adjective OR between that and the "augmented" attribute introduced by the ***as-*** clause. Note that the two words in the corresponding ***more than*** version may need to be split, so *I feel sad **more than** angry* becomes *I feel **more** sad **than** angry* when rephrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't feel so much angry as sad.

Yes, this is correct.

Written in full, it would be, *I don't feel so much angry as I feel sad*

---

Edit in response to comment by @Cheng

> I don't feel angry so much as sad

The long form of this is *I don't feel angry so much as I feel sad* - This differs in word order from the previously mentioned expanded sentence.

Comment: Do you have any comments on: I don't feel angry so much as sad. (the first sentence)?

Comment: @Cheng -  Please can you say what sort of comments you are interested in? I've added one to the answer.

Comment: @ chasly - supports Monica Let me update my question to make it clearer. Sorry!